# AVR C: Int to hexadecimal address

Tags: c, avr

Working with AVR GCC on an Atmega1284P, I used to have the following:

```
#define CMP_START_ADDR 0x18000
static UInt32 loadingAddr = CMP_START_ADDR;
static UInt32 newCmpAddr = CMP_START_ADDR;
```

Where, e.g. loadingAddr ,  is used as follows somewhere (as an address):

```
        boot_program_page(loadingAddr,block_page);
```

and where UInt32 is typedef unsigned long UInt32;

Now I want the same setup but as follows:

```
#define CMP_START_ADDR ROM_SIZE-RESERVED_CMP_ROM_SPACE

static UInt8 amount_of_files = 0;
static UInt32 loadingAddr = CMP_START_ADDR;
static UInt32 newCmpAddr = CMP_START_ADDR;
```

Where ROM_SIZE and RESERVED_CMP_ROM_SPACE are respectively defined somewhere as:

```
    #define ROM_SIZE            FLASHEND
    #define RESERVED_CMP_ROM_SPACE  28000
```

And FLASHEND is from iom128.h:

```
#define FLASHEND   0x1FFFF
```

The new code compiles but does not work. I assume the address goes wrong because I'm using integers and hexadecimals inconsistently. How would I most efficiently resolve this?

Comment: "I assume the address goes wrong because I'm using integers and hexadecimals inconsistently." - That assumption is wrong. decimal, binary, hexa-decimal and octal literals are all perfectly compatible.

Comment: Indeed the bug is not related to hex, but something else. It will be impossible for anyone to re-produce it with the code given.

Comment: Try and run gcc with the `-save-temps` option. Then locate the file `<c-filename>.i` and see what e.g. `loadingAddr` gets really initialized to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RESERVED_CMP_ROM_SPACE  28000
```

28000 is not page aligned so if your implementation of `boot_program_page` is the one [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__boot.html) the program will compile and even do something but not write the program you expect.
If you read the memory with a debugger after bootload I think you will observe something like a3a1a2b3b1b2c3c1c2  instead of a1a2a3b1b2b3c1c2c3.

Try with `RESERVED_CMP_ROM_SPACE  32768`